# How to convert list object to string list

Tags: python, string

I have problem with converting

**[['a'],['b'],['c']] --> ['a','b','c']**

it seems simple but I am struggling for hours...

Comment: `[x[0] for x in input_list]`.

Comment: Pls show us what you have tried. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension to do something as simple as

```
[element[0] for element in letters_list]
```

This remakes the list, extracting the 0-index element from each sublist